# How can I prove if $x>0$ then $-x<0$?

Tags: inequality, arithmetic

$$x>0\implies-x<0$$

I thought about using the axioms of multiplication with $x\cdot (-1) = -x$
 but I am kind of stuck there.

Comment: How about adding $-x$ to both sides?

Comment: I feel stupid. But thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

**$If x>0 then 0=-x+x>-x+0 so that -x<0. If x<0 then 0=-x+x<-x+0 so that -x>0$**